# Handling two independent gems that cause compatible version issue for Bundler

Tags: ruby, bundler

If I have a Gemfile that is

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'
gem "heckle", "~> 2.0.0.b1"
gem "reek", "~> 1.3.2"
```

Then I get the error message

```
Fetching gem metadata from https://rubygems.org/.........
Resolving dependencies...
Bundler could not find compatible versions for gem "ruby_parser":
  In Gemfile:
    reek (~> 1.3.2) ruby depends on
      ruby_parser (~> 3.1.1) ruby

    heckle (~> 2.0.0.b1) ruby depends on
      ruby_parser (2.3.1)
```

Is it possible to tell Bundler that heckle and reek don't need to work with each other, and therefore it's ok to have two versions of ruby_parser?

For those unfamiliar with the two gems involved, heckle and reek are both gems that provide executables that analyse source code. They don't need to be required by code.

Comment: If they don’t need to be required by any code then why do they need to be in your Gemfile?

Comment: @AndrewMarshall I assume consistency is good, even for executables.

Comment: It’s not the consistency it’s more that it’s not an actual dependency of your app. You can have multiple Gemfiles, btw, if it seems reasonable to separate such things in that way.